# How should Go library code initialize and use random number generation?

Tags: go

When writing a Go *library* that needs to use random numbers, what is the best way to initialize and consume random numbers?

I know that the std way to do this in an application is:

```
import (
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

// do the initial seeding in an init fn
func init() {
    // set the global seed and use the global fns
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(rand.Int())
    fmt.Println(rand.Intn(200))
}
```

So when I'm writing library code (not in the main package), should I just do the same:

```
package libfoo

func init() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
}

func AwesomeFoo() {
    r :=  rand.Intn(1000)
    // ...
}
```

The application using my library might also do its own random number seeding and use `rand.Intn`, so my question really is - is there any downside to having a library seed the random number generator and some app code (or another library) do so as well?

Also is there any issue with the library using the "global" `rand.Intn` or `rand.Int` or should a library create it's own private `Rand` object via `rand.New(src)` and use that instead?

I don't have any particular reason for thinking this is unsafe, but I know enough about crypto and PRNGs to know that it is easy to get something wrong if you don't know what you're doing.

For example, here's a simple library for the Knuth (Fisher-Yates) shuffle that needs randomness: https://gist.github.com/quux00/8258425

Comment: Personally, I would use something similar to dependency injection. First define an interface for a random number generator that matches the functionality you need from the standard library's rand.Rand type, then define an opaque type with a constructor that takes anything that implements that interface and then exposes your library's functionality through method calls. That way an application can use whatever random number generator they want and seed it however they like, then apply that to your library's functionality.

Comment: After looking over the "math/rand" documentation, I would use the rand.Source interface to allow application code to seed the library by passing a Source object to a constructor object. Then you can use the rand.Rand object internally with whatever seeded source the application passes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's best really just depends on the type of application you're writing and the type of library you want to create. If we're not sure, we can get the most flexibility by using a form of dependency injection through Go interfaces.

Consider the following naive Monte Carlo integrator that takes advantage of the `rand.Source` interface:

```
package monte

import (
    "math/rand"
)

const (
    DEFAULT_STEPS = 100000
)

type Naive struct {
    rand *rand.Rand
    steps int
}

func NewNaive(source rand.Source) *Naive {
    return &Naive{rand.New(source), DEFAULT_STEPS}
}

func (m *Naive) SetSteps(steps int) {
    m.steps = steps
}

func (m *Naive) Integrate1D(fn func(float64) float64, a, b float64) float64 {
    var sum float64
    for i := 0; i < m.steps; i++ {
        x := (b-a) * m.rand.Float64() 
        sum += fn(x)
    }
    return (b-a)*sum/float64(m.steps)
}
```

We can then use this package to calculate the value of pi:

```
func main() {
    m := monte.NewNaive(rand.NewSource(200))
    pi := 4*m.Integrate1D(func (t float64) float64 {
        return math.Sqrt(1-t*t)
    }, 0, 1)
    fmt.Println(pi)
}
```

In this case, the quality of our algorithm's results depend on the type of pseudorandom number generator used, so we need to provide a way for users to swap out one generator for another. Here we've defined an opaque type that takes a random number source in its constructor. By having their random number generator satisfy the rand.Source interface, our application writer can then swap out random number generators as needed.

However, there are many cases where this is exactly what we don't want to do. Consider a random password or key generator. In that case, what we really want is a high entropy source of truly random data, so we should just use the `crypto/rand` package internally and hide the details from our application writers:

```
package keygen

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base32"
)

func GenKey() (string, error) {
    b := make([]byte, 20)
    if _, err := rand.Read(b); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    enc := base32.NewEncoding("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ346789")
    return enc.EncodeToString(b), nil
}
```

Hopefully that helps you make a decision. If the code is for your own applications or applications within a specific company rather than industry wide or public use, lean towards the library design that exposes the fewest internals and creates the fewest dependencies rather than the most general design, since that will ease maintenance and shorten implementation time.

Basically, if it feels like overkill, it probably is.

In the case of the Knuth Shuffle, the requirements are simply a decent psuedo-random number generator, so you could simply use an internally seeded rand.Rand object that's private to your package like so:

```
package shuffle

import (
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

var r *rand.Rand

func init() {
    r = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()))
}

func ShuffleStrings(arr []string) {
    last := len(arr)-1
    for i := range arr {
        j := r.Intn(last)
        arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
    }
}
```

Then the application doesn't have to worry about how it works:

```
package main

import (
    "shuffle"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    arr := []string{"a","set","of","words"}
    fmt.Printf("Shuffling words: %v\n", arr)
    for i := 0; i<10; i++ {
        shuffle.ShuffleStrings(arr)
        fmt.Printf("Shuffled words: %v\n", arr)
    }
}
```

This prevents the application from accidentally reseeding the random number generator used by your package by calling rand.Seed.

Comment: Thanks - these are excellent examples. To your point on overkill, for the `knuth.Shuffle` type of example, I would argue that a standard (non-crypto quality) PRNG should be fine and there's not much reason to require an app user of the library to pass in a PNRG. Or at least provide a ctor that doesn't require it. Your  Depedency Injection model also requires one to design the library with methods, rather than functions. In some cases methods just aren't needed/appropriate.

Comment: I didn't address the Knuth Shuffle, but I'd say my suggestions are mostly overkill. You could just create a single static `rand.Rand` object seeded in the package's init function and use that internally. That insulates the package from being affected by the application calling `rand.Seed()`, which is something you'd have to worry about with your original code. If later it turns out that seeding the package's internal random number generator is necessary from outside the package (say for testing/reproducing results), you can always add a Seed function to the package. :)

Comment: I edited my answer and added an example to show what I'm talking about. One of the most important thing when designing a library is ensuring your code is insulated from the side-effects of application code. Nothing happening completely outside your package's code should affect its internal state. That'd be my only concern with using the rand.Intn and rand.Seed functions in a library.

Answer (score 4):

Don't seed the global random number generator. That should be left to package main.

If you care what your seed is, you should create your own private Rand object. If you don't care, you can just use the global source.

If you care about your numbers actually being random, you should use crypto/rand instead of math/rand.

Comment: Based on your answer and @James' comment: *first*, the library should not seed the global PRNG; *second*: one's library has to make a choice - **(1)** document and require that the app be aware that the library requires it to do the seeding. Also potentially provide a way to allow the app to inject PRNG functionality into your lib. *Or* **(2)** keep it opaque to the app writer and either seed only your personal `math.rand.Rand` object or use the crypto/rand library (which seems not to require seeding).  How to choose between the options?  Depends on what the library is doing, perhaps?

Comment: Of course it depends on what the library is doing. (By the way, you're right about crypto/rand; it doesn't require seeding. It uses a random-number source provided by the operating system, and that gets its "seeds" from various sources.)

Comment: The "math/rand" package is more useful for numerical applications, like Monte Carlo simulations or video games, especially if you need the application to be able to provide rand.Source implementations with different properties or based on different pseudo-random number generators. If you're not doing something numerical in nature, then you probably want to use crypto/rand.

Comment: Also: If your package can concurrently access the random number generator and you want to prevent using the same generated random number in more than once place, use a mutex on the underlying source. See the standard library's implementation of lockedSrc: https://golang.org/src/math/rand/rand.go?#L252